# .NET CORE | Como tratar campos que não podem ser alterados (DIsabled ou Readonly)

Tags: javascript, html5, .net, asp.net-core

tenho uma dúvida conceitual que pode ser básica.

Cenário é o seguinte: Tenho um campo que deve aparecer para o usuário, é uma numeração sequencial que em um determinado momento será enviado pelo Submit da página.

Se colocar o disabled no campo, o valor não é enviado no submit.
Se colocar o readonly, não consigo atualizar a tela antes do envio para que o usuário possa ver o valor.

Tem alguma forma de tratar esse cenário?

Muito obrigado pessoal

Comment: Não parece ser uma questão conceitual, parece só erro de código mesmo.

Comment: Maniero, não entendi. Pode me falar um pouco mais sobre?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo, realmente inputs disabled não são enviados pelo submit.
Uma solução seria você criar um `<input type="hidden">` igual ao disabled, este por sua vez vai estar oculto do usuário e poderá ser enviado pois não estará disabled.